# Old Prelims exam question on Krylov subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Assume $H = Q^{*} AQ$ where $Q \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is unitary and $H$ is unreduced upper Hessenberg. Denote the columns of $Q$ as $q_1,q_2,\ldots,q_n.$

*Note that in our course $Q^{*}$ is the complex conjugate transpose of $Q$.  I.e. take the transpose, then take the complex conjugate term by term.*

a) Express the Krylov subspace $K_{j}(A,q_{1})$ using only $q_{1}$ and powers of $A$.

*Solution:* $K_{j}( A,q_{1}) = \left\{q_{1}, Aq_{1}, A^{2}q_{1} ,\ldots,A^{j-1} q_{1}\right\}$

b) Show that
$$K_{j}(A,q_{1}) = \operatorname{span} \{q_{1},q_{2} ,\ldots, q_{j}\},\qquad j = 1,2,...,n.$$

I have a feeling it has something to do with the characteristic polynomial of $A$, but I'm really not sure how to approach this. I have:

$$A = QHQ^{*} \\
K_{j}(A,q_{1}) = \left\{q_{1}, QHQ^{*} q_{1}, QH^{2}Q^{*}q_{1} ,\ldots,QH^{j-1}Q{^{*}} q_{1}\right\}$$

EDIT - responding to Lutz's answer below, I have my inductive solution. Not sure if this is elegant, or even correct.

Inductive hypothesis: suppose:  $$K_{j-1}(A,q_{1}) = \left\{q_{1}, QHQ^{*}q_{1}, QH^{2}Q^{*}q_{1}, \ldots, QH^{j-2}Q^{*}q_{1}\right\}$$
Also suppose: $$K_{j-1}(A,q_{1}) = \operatorname{span}\{q_{1}, q_{2}, \ldots, q_{j-1}\}$$
Induction Step: Adding a vector to the krylov space, $A^{j-1}q_{1}$ implies that for some coefficients $\{c_{1}, c_{2}, \ldots, c_{j}\},  j = 1,\ldots, n-1,$
$$A^{j-1} q_{1} =QH^{j-1}Q^{*}q_{1} = QH^{j-1}e_{1} = c_{1}q_{1} + c_{2}q_{2} + \ldots + c_{j} q_{j} .$$
If $h_{j,j-1} \neq 0,$ then
$$K_{j}(A,q_{1}) = \operatorname{span}\{q_{1}, q_{2},\ldots, q_{j}\}$$

Since adding a vector to $j-1$ implies it holds for $j$, it holds for all $j = 1,\ldots,n$.

Comment: Hi all, I'm new here and noticed my question got a downvote. Why on earth would that happen? Is it just not interesting enough?

Comment: Usually people downvote because they feel like the post doesn't have enough 'context' or 'effort' from the asker. The implementation of this site-wide policy/etiquette is often controversial

Comment: Also, you should avoid putting text into math mode.  It makes it nigh impossible to read on some displays.

Comment: I just copied latex from mathch.io. Should I do that differently? Is there a tutorial?

Comment: @MarcdeVernon We use MathJax (in an html context) here, so not all LaTex will transfer seamlessly.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for future posts. Apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next step $Q^*q_1=e_1$, $He_1=(h_{11},h_{21},0,…,0)^T$, so that
$$
Aq_1=QHQ^*q_1=h_{11}q_1+h_{21}q_2.
$$
This means that $K_2$ is either $span\{q_1\}$ if $h_{21}=0$ or is $span\{q_1,q_2\}$.

Comment: I was not sure how to post my follow up, but I wanted to check if the inductive case makes sense to you?  I posted it as an answer below.

Comment: I updated my original question, and followed your advice about the incorrect j's. I also labeled my inductive step and hypothesis and treated the hj,j+1 = 0 case. I think its good and would be happy to check your answer as the best one and close this if you think the solution in my post looks ok.